# Switch Expressions in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I'll preface this question with, I already have the answer. But I suspect other people ran into similar scenarios and I wanted to share my solution.

Question: How can I use a switch expression in Balzor to render components?

I have a scenario where I have an object with a string property and I want to render different buttons based on the string value. Using a switch statement it looks something like this

```cs
@switch(myObject.SomeStringValue)
{
    case "StringValueOne": <ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoAThing"/> break;
    case "StringValueTwo": <ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoTwoThing"/> break;
    case "StringValueThree": <ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoThreeThing"/> break;
    default: <ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoSomethingElse"/> break;
}
```

My problem is I wanted to match multiple string values in each case, using pattern matching...

```cs
 case is "StringValueOne" or "AnotherMatchingValue": <ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoAThing"/> break;
```

Based on the C# docs, I couldn't find a way to use a switch statement and pattern matching together.

Now, in general I like the syntax of switch expressions better than switch statements. I wanted to be able to use a switch expression in Blazor to get a similar outcome to the above switch statement which works natively in a razor file. How could I use a switch expression to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Did you try to ommit `break;` between 2 cases? `case "abc": case "def": <foo> break;`

Comment: A great option as well, but I like the succinctness of the switch expressions and pattern matching.  Additionally, I am anticipating a number of matches, like....
``` cs
"valueone" or "valuetwo" or "valuethree" or "value four"
```
Which looks cleaner than a bunch of case statements strung together.

edit: pressed the enter button instead of shift+enter

Comment: A matter of taste I guess, as I'd rather see all options aligned with `case`s and line breaks than a really long line of `or`s :) cleaner is subjective

Answer (score 9):

Well, here's an answer folks!

```cs
@(myObject.SomeStringValue switch
{
    "StringValueOne" or "AnotherMatch" => (@<ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoAThing"/>),
    "StringValueTwo" or "MatchTwo" => (@<ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoTwoThing"/>),
    "StringValueThree" or "MatchThree" => (@<ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoThreeThing"/>),
    _ => (@<ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoSomethingElse"/>)
})
```

Let me know if you find another way to do this or if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 4):

For simple strings, you could also just have multiple case statements like this:

```cs
@switch(myObject.SomeStringValue)
{
    case "StringValueOne":
    case "AnotherMatchingValue":
        <ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoAThing"/>
        break;
    case "StringValueTwo": <ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoTwoThing"/> break;
    case "StringValueThree": <ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoThreeThing"/> break;
    default: <ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoSomethingElse"/> break;
}
```

Both `StringValueOne` and `AnotherMatchingValue` will result in `<ButtonComponent OnClick="@DoAThing"/>`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is "expensive", you're re-creating the component just to change one of the parameters - `OnClick`.  The sledgehammer to crack a nut!

Here's some code that demonstrates how to "switch" `OnClick` based on some input.  You can assign any `delegate` to  `OnClick` that matches it's signature.  `Action`'s are packaged delegates we can use for the purpose.

As you haven't shown `ButtonComponent` I've made up a very simple one:

```cs
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.ButtonClicked>Click Me</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback Clicked { get; set; }

    private void ButtonClicked()
        => Clicked.InvokeAsync();
}
```

Here's a test page to demo things in action:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<ButtonComponent Clicked=this.buttonHandler />

<div class="m-3 text-right text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.ChangeInt>Change Delegate</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
    @switcher - @this.message
</div>

@code {
    private int switcher = 0;
    private string message = "Nothing Clicked";

    private Action buttonHandler => switcher switch
    {
        1 => Do1,
        2 => Do2,
        3 => Do3,
        _ => Do0
    };

    private void ChangeInt()
        => switcher = switcher >= 3 ? 0 : ++switcher;

    private void Do0()
        => message = $"Switch0 clicked";

    private void Do1()
        => message = $"Switch1 clicked";

    private void Do2()
        => message = $"Switch2 clicked";

    private void Do3()
        => message = $"Switch3 clicked";
}
```